# Signed and unsigned packed integer?

Tags: integer, size

What is the largest and smallest integer that can be represented by one byte in a signed and unsigned **packed** integer?

Comment: What is a "packed integer" in this context?

Comment: This was a question from my old exam, it read "A given microprocessor has words of one byte" and then it asked for the largest and smallest integer that can be represented by one byte

Comment: Why not ask your professor then?

Comment: Because I am writing this exam tomorrow...

Answer (score 0):

one byte is 8 bits.so yo can save 0-255 unsigned integer and -128 to 127 of signed integer value in one byte.

Comment: Is there a difference between an "unsigned packed integer" and an "unsigned integer"? Sorry for this stupid question, I just cant find the answer anywhere

Comment: there is no "first" bit in packed data.if your professor purpose is that,so they are difference ... therefore  we can save 0-127 in unsigned packed integer.